# tensorboard ImportErrorの原因について

Tags: python, tensorflow

cmdにてtensorboardのサーバを起動させようとして

```
tensorboard —logdir=./logfile
```

と入力すると下記のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

> ImportError: cannot import name lazy
> 下記にエラーが出た際のcmd画面を載せます。
> [image: ImportError時の画面]

tensorflowを再インストールしてみても、
下記のリンク先の方法を確かめてみても、
エラーは解消しませんでした。
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/1862

どなたか同様の現象に会われている方は
いますでしょうか？
また、原因がわかる方がいましたら
ご教示願います。

#### 環境

- OS: Windows 8.1
- Python: 3.6.3
- tensorflow: 1.14.0
- tensorboard: 1.14.0
- tensorflow-estimator: 1.14.0
- anacondaを使用してpython環境をインストールしています。
  -tensorboard.exeがあるディレクトリのパスを通しております。

また、
condaで新たな環境(環境名：py363_for_tensorflow)を構築し、tensorflowをインストール後にtensorboardを実行しましたが、やはり同じエラー(ImportError)が出てしまします。その時のスタックトレースは下記のようになっています。
[image: 別環境を構築後のエラー]

別環境でインストールしたtensorflowのバージョンは次のようになっております。
[image: 新環境tensorflowバージョン]

Comment: 出力されたエラーはその1行だけでしょうか？スタックトレースが出力されているのであれば、それも載せた方が回答を得やすいと思います。

Comment: Kohei TAMURA様　ご指摘ありがとうございます。エラー出力時のcmdの写真を追加いたしました。

Answer (score 0):

tensorboardをインストールしたディレクトリでコマンドを実行しているのですか？そのせいでモジュールの読み込みが上手くいっていないのではないのでしょうか？

Comment: tensorboardをインストールしたディレクトリでコマンドを実行しております。ただし、他のディレクトリでコマンドを実行した場合も同様のエラーが出てしまいます。私の認識では、tensorboard.exeのあるディレクトリのパスさえ通しておけばカレントディレクトリはどこであっても、エラーなく実行できると思っていたのですが、tensorboardをインストールしたディレクトリでコマンドを実行した場合、不具合が起こるものなのでしょうか？

Comment: ごめんなさい。この場合モジュール検索パスにカレントディレクトリが含まれる事はありませんでした。condaを使われてるようなので新しく環境を作成してそこにインストールされてみてはどうでしょうか

Comment: そうなのですね。承知いたしました。condaで新しく環境構築後インストールしてみます。

Comment: condaで新たな環境(環境名：py363_for_tensorflow)を構築し、tensorflowをインストール後にtensorboardを実行しましたが、やはり同じエラー(ImportError)が出てしまします。その時のスタックトレースを上記の説明欄に追記しました。